# Установка MSVC Runtime 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

При запуске питон скрипта скрипт падает с ошибкой

> ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

Запустил Process Explorer и вижу, что процесс не находит модуль `msvcr90.dll`

Поставил Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package. DLL появились, но по странному пути

> c:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375\

И питон их по прежнему не видит

```
16:05:31,6992098    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   E:\csvn\Python25\Lib\site-packages\mercurial\cext\MSVCR90.dll   NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,6994773    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR90.dll NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,6997268    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system\MSVCR90.dll   NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,6999067    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\MSVCR90.dll  NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7001471    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\Inetpub\hg\MSVCR90.dll   NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7003261    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\Support Tools\MSVCR90.dll  NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7006617    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   E:\csvn\bin\MSVCR90.dll NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7008847    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   E:\csvn\Python25\MSVCR90.dll    NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7010852    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\MSVCR90.dll    NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7013275    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR90.dll NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7015105    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\MSVCR90.dll  NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7018045    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\MSVCR90.dll    NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7020855    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\MSVCR90.dll NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7023043    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\Program Files\PHP\MSVCR90.dll    NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7026129    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\MSVCR90.dll  NAME NOT FOUND  
16:05:31,7029459    python.exe  4112    QueryOpen   C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\MSVCR90.dll  NAME NOT FOUND
```

Т.е. поиск производится только по переменной `PATH`. Хотя `comctl32.dll` отлично находится по подобному пути

```
16:05:30,4482779    python.exe  4112    CreateFile  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.5190_x-ww_319264BE\comctl32.dll   SUCCESS
```

Вопрос, что я делаю не так и как этот пакет правильно поставить? ОС Windows 2003

Comment: А ты обе битности поставил?

Comment: @donRumata Нет. у меня система 32 бита

Comment: А если через `regsvr` прорегать?

Comment: @donRumata Так они же не COM-овские